# android action bar overlay issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay, android-support-library

all, I tired to make a action bar overlay the layout of my activity. I am also use support library to support `android` 2.1 and above, the layout of my activity is as follows:

```
<!-- activity_display_message.xml in layout folder -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `manifest.xml` is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

    <!-- some code for main activity -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The `styles.xml` which defines `CustomActionBarTheme` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now the problem when applied `CustomActionBarTheme` is that the text (passed from main activity) which supposed to be displayed in the `TextView` of `display_message_activity` disappeared, so I am guessing if it is due to the overlay action bar that covers the text message, and so anyone has any idea how to solve the issue?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the cause that doesn't show your text and to solve your problem you should set margin top for TextView with the value: `?attr/actionBarSize`

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

I hope you have solved your problem and this is a correct answer :)